# Am I allowed to do this when evaluating a limit for a Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

By the Continuity & Convergence Theorem: $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$.

Letting $a_n = \sin(1/n)$, we want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/n)$.

Can I do $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/n) = \sin(1/ \infty) = \sin(0) = 0\,$?

Or is it better to do: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/n) = \sin[\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)] = \sin[(1/ \infty)] = \sin[(0)] = 0\;?$$

Or, do I have to use substitution, as follows?

$$r = \lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=1/ \infty = 0,$$

$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\sin(r) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(0) = 0.$$

This means it converges to $0$ by the theorem.

Which methods are sufficient to use?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} x\right)$ is definition of continuity.

Comment: No, you cannot do "$\cdots 1/\infty \cdots$".

Comment: Suggestion: write $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n=0$ and do not write $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n=1/\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods you have written are just different formulations of the same thing. If we set $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then what you want to compute is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(b_n)$. By what you wrote in the start, using that $\sin$ is continuous and that $b_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, we get that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin(0)=0.$$

I'd say the key part here that you **should** be careful with is when you use $\infty$ as if it was a number. Indeed if you just remove the $\infty$-part, your argument is perfectly formal and rigorous (assuming you already know that $\sin$ us continuous etc.).